# Limit of psql_history

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I can't find (using `ctrl-r` within `psql` and `less ~/.psql_history`) a particular query that I executed a couple months back. I also recently upgraded from 9.3 to 9.5 so I'm not sure if there is a limit on `psql_history` or if it was removed on the upgrade.

Is there a limit on the size of `psql_history` and, if so, how could I go about increasing it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `psql` variable that sets the number of commands to save in the history:

```
postgres=# \set HISTSIZE 100
postgres=# \echo :HISTSIZE
100
postgres=#
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> HISTSIZE - The number of commands to store in the command history. The
>   default value is 500

You can set it in your `~/.psqlrc`.

Answer (score 2):

In many Linux setups, you execute `psql` via the `postgres` user. In this case, you would want to create `/var/lib/postgres/.psql_history` and make sure it’s read/writeable by postgres. Then edit `/var/lib/postgres/.psqlrc` and add in the options to save your psql_history…

Here it is in a script:

```sh
# Enable .psql_history.
sudo touch /var/lib/postgres/{.psql_history,.psqlrc}
sudo chown postgres /var/lib/postgres/{.psql_history,.psqlrc}
sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/postgres/.psql_history

# Set history to the max possible:
echo \set HISTSIZE 2147483647 | sudo tee -a /var/lib/postgres/.psqlrc

# You might also want to add this to have a MUCH MUCH better pager:
echo \setenv PAGER 'less -SFi'  | sudo tee -a /var/lib/postgres/.psqlrc
```